# Needs to get the name from a List<> to be written in a richtextbox

Tags: c#, list, richtextbox

I am trying to get the name from some goods added on a List<>. These names have to be written in a richtextbox, but I can't get fixed. I can see that I'm on the right direction, because it gets all the goods i want, but it just can't write the name in the box.

All i can see when Im debugging is:

Mandag
Navn:
Navn:
Navn:
Navn:
Navn:
Navn:
Navn:
Navn:
Navn:

Hope someone helps me. Thx!

```
        richTextBox_lister.Clear();
        string listenavn = comboBox1.Text;
        int listenr = Convert.ToInt32(ictrInd.GetListeNr(listenavn));
        Indkøbsliste indkø = ictrInd.findIndkøbsliste(listenr);

        listofIndk = ictrInd.getListerIndkøb(indkø);

        int i;
        string s;
        s =  comboBox1.Text +"\n";
        for (i =0; i <= (listofIndk.Count -1); i++)
        {
            s = s + "Navn:  " + listofIndk[i].Navn + "\n";
        }
        richTextBox_lister.Text = s;
```

Comment: I don't see any mention of a List there?

Comment: how do you create listofIndk ? (what type is it and what happenes in ictrInd.getListerIndkøb(indkø))

Comment: List<Indkøbsliste> listofIndk

the method: getListerIndkøb(indkø) gets all goods with the same listNr, and then returning them inside a List<>.

Comment: If you debug from Visual Studio, can you see all the correct entries in listofIndk?

Comment: Are you Navn's variables in list is not empty?

Comment: What? Don't know what you talking about. I'm new to VS.. Can you do that? :)

Comment: Reniuz - hmm, maybe. Let me just look at the database coding :)

Comment: EVERYBODY

Thanks for all the answersYou cant see the forest for trees. 
I found the foul in my database coding, and now it works. It was a typing mistake from me. 
Thanks again!

Comment: You don't need to look at database coding. Just set breakpoint(lets say on `Int i;` line) and inspect your list while debugging. When breakpoint hits move your mouse cursor over `listofIndk` and you can see your list content.

Comment: Reniuz - oh thank you. I'll try that next time! Thank you again! :)

Comment: So fantasticfix was right - you should accept his answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this compiles the only possibility is that the properties "Navn" are empty / uninitialized. Check in the method ictrInd.getListerIndkøb(indkø) with the debugger if "Navn" is set. Otherwise post more code.